How to *reduce* head retention?
The opposite of most head retention questions, I want to REDUCE head retention.  Ideally to "none".
My goal is to make my existing recipe extremely fizzy (soda-pop levels of fizz) that doesn't just over-foam the glass.
Any hints?

There isn't any one single factor which gives beer good head retention but by and large I've heard that protein is the main piece of it. Barley, yeast, hops and other adjuncts will contribute to it also. Often, I've added wheat malt in recipes to help get better retention. Apparently wheat has more protein content than barley[1] along with some other "stuff".
You may want to try a recipe with low protein content ingredients. Something like a "light" beer comes to mind. If you end up with a 3% recipe and want a little more kick, you can add table/corn sugar during the last 10 mins of the boil to boost the ABV without adding protein. There are drawbacks to this however so be aware[2].
PS: I'm not sure if rice is lower in protein than other constituents, but that may be something to look into as well.
[1] https://beerandbrewing.com/dictionary/VRMMRkwdtG/
[2] https://www.morebeer.com/questions/207

I'm trying to reduce head retention in an existing recipe (original clarified), so replacing the grains and adding sugar aren't really good options.  From your suggestion, though, I'm going to experiment with a long protein rest and see if that helps.  Thanks!

You bet , and good luck. Post back if it works!
